# Google Maps unthaws "itself"?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-maps, titanium-backup, disable-app

I have a relatively specific question - I'm on a SonyEricsson xPeria Mini Pro (sk17i), using Android 4.0.4 with a rooted Stock Rom.

To conserve battery, I'm regularly freezing some apps I only use occasionaly (like FB, Skype, and also Google Maps), using Titanium Backup. They would otherwise run in the background permanently, which I don't want them to do.

The thing I experienced is, that Google Maps somehow seems capable of unthawing itself - once in a while it returns to running in background.

Anyone else noticed this? Is there a way to prevent Google Maps from doing so (Or more likely prevent the Android OS from unthawing Maps)?

Thanks for the answers

Comment: Have you checked if the *app* is really *unthawed*? I rather guess something was calling one of its *intents* explicitly. Explanation: When an app is frozen, it becomes unavailable/invisible in the drawer etc. and is excluded from autostart (it no longer listens to broadcasts, it seems). But it is still possible to directly start its intents, as they are obviously not removed from system configuration by most "freezers".

Comment: Unthawing seems an odd choice of work. Thawing means to no longer be frozen, so unthawing surely is a way of saying it's returning to freezing, so why use it to refer to something which has started running again?

Answer (score 0):

Running in background does not mean the app did "unthaw" itself. To understand this, some background information might be helpful:

"Freezing" actually doesn't change the app or uninstall it. It just marks it as "unavailable", so it no longer shows up in the app drawer etc. It should also no longer receive broadcasts. But it's still there. So if another app knows its "intents", it could explicitly call them ­– and they would respond. This is what most likely happens here: Something is placing an explicit call to it.

---

Before freezing *Maps*, I've disabled some of its "listeners" (I do no longer remember which ones), which can be done with several apps, e.g. [Autorun Manager Pro](http://www.appbrain.com/app/autorun-manager-pro/com.rs.autorun.pro) or [ROM Toolbox Pro](http://www.appbrain.com/app/rom-toolbox-pro/com.jrummy.liberty.toolboxpro). For me, Maps no longer wakes up.

I'd recommend you taking a look at *Autorun Manager* (you might check its free version first). As it offers both, freezing and receiver-blocking, it would be the first choice concerning this. Oh, same applies for *ROM Manager*, by the way, which also offers a free version. So you've got the choice to check them both, comparing, and then deciding which one to buy – as full functionality in both cases only comes with the payed versions.

PS: AFAIR the dev of *Autorun Manager* wanted to implement a freezing method which automatically un-registers receivers. So you might want to check that one first.